# How to use single quote inside a EXECUTE statement SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

how to get this code executed in SQLSERVER

```
BEGIN 
    EXECUTE('CREATE VIEW [dbo].[dummy] AS select cid,CASE 
        WHEN email IS NOT NULL
            THEN 'RESTRICTED' + right(email, patindex('%@%', reverse(email)))
        ELSE NULL
        END as email_id
from (
select 11 as cid,'abcd123@email.com' as email
) A')
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    BEGIN 
        EXECUTE('CREATE VIEW [dbo].[dummy] AS select cid,CASE 
            WHEN email IS NOT NULL
                THEN ''RESTRICTED'' + right(email, patindex(''%@%'', reverse(email)))
            ELSE NULL
            END as email_id
    from (
    select 11 as cid,''abcd123@email.com'' as email
    ) A')
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Double the single quotes:

```
BEGIN 
    EXECUTE('CREATE VIEW [dbo].[dummy] AS SELECT 1 AS Dummy ,''hello'' as name')
END
```

Comment: yes this works! But, I'm trying to execute something like this:              `code`  **bold** BEGIN 
    EXECUTE('CREATE VIEW [dbo].[dummy] AS select cid,CASE 
  WHEN email IS NOT NULL
   THEN 'RESTRICTED' + right(email, patindex('%@%', reverse(email)))
  ELSE NULL
  END as email_id
from (
select 11 as cid,'abcd123@email.com' as email
) A')
END